# Create column in fetchrequest based on expression

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller

**SUMMARY**

I want to be able to *create* a new value based on an expression in a fetchRequest from a Core Data entity.

Having an entity with this attributes (short version)

```
  Name              Attributes
[Course] -> {licenseStart, name, id}
```

I want to make a fetchResquest on that entity and retrieve a dictionary with all the attributes plus one more base on this expression:

`licenseStart.doubleValue / 1000 < NSDate().timeIntervalSince1970 ? "Actually" : "Cooming Soon"`

So the result will be:

```
[ "licenseStart":1,"id":3, "name":"A", "status":0, ...
  "licenseStart":2,"id":4, "name":"B", "status":0, ...
  "licenseStart":3,"id":6, "name":"B", "status":0, ...
  "licenseStart":4,"id":2, "name":"C", "status":0, ...
  "licenseStart":5,"id":1, "name":"D", "status":1, ...
  "licenseStart":6,"id":7, "name":"E", "status":1, ...
]
```

**POST**

I want to ask a question for a problem that I'm being facing since a couple of days now.. every approach I've tried ends up with a more complex solution.

Let me explain to you the situation:

I have a CoreData Model with an entity that has different attributes, one of them is **license start** this is a unix timestamp number that is used to determinate when a course will start.

So, when I want to populate the data to create a UITableView with the courses I am fetching all this information from database with no problem at all, I use this **licenseStart** attribute to calculate the sections based on a formula, this is the code for UITableView

**UITableViewController**

```
let entity = NSEntityDescription.entityForName("Course", inManagedObjectContext: managedObjectContext!)
        let req = NSFetchRequest()
        let predicate = sectionProtocol?.FRCPredicate
        let sort = [NSSortDescriptor(key: "licenseStart", ascending: true), NSSortDescriptor(key: "name", ascending: true), NSSortDescriptor(key: "courseId", ascending: true)]
        req.entity = entity
        req.sortDescriptors = sort
        req.predicate = predicate
        /* NSFetchedResultsController initialization
        a 'nil' 'sectionNameKeyPath' generates a single section */
        var aFetchedResultsController = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: req, managedObjectContext: managedObjectContext!, sectionNameKeyPath:"dateStatus", cacheName: nil)
```

After this my results are (small example) like this

```
[ "licenseStart":1,"id":3, "name":"A",...
  "licenseStart":2,"id":4, "name":"B",...
  "licenseStart":3,"id":6, "name":"B",...
  "licenseStart":4,"id":2, "name":"C",...
  "licenseStart":5,"id":1, "name":"D",...
  "licenseStart":6,"id":7, "name":"E",
]
```

What I'll have in the UITableView will be:

```
[Actually] 
  [A]
  [B]
  [B]
  [C]
[Cooming Soon]
  [D]
  [E]
```

So, what I do now is using the **licenseStart** to create two sections, how?, easy, just using a attribute of my model called **dateStatus** and creating two possible results using the license start as follows:

**ModelClass**

```
var dateStatus : Int {
        get {
            return licenseStart.doubleValue / 1000 < NSDate().timeIntervalSince1970 ? "Actually" : "Cooming Soon"
        }
 }
```

So again in my UITableView I use the dataSource delegates methods for populate the rows and the sections.

**PROBLEM**

Until now everything works perfect. But now I want to add a sort option that let the users sort the results ascending or descending, the problem is that when I sort in, i.e, ascending using a different sort option:

```
let entity = NSEntityDescription.entityForName("Course", inManagedObjectContext: managedObjectContext!)
        let req = NSFetchRequest()
        let predicate = sectionProtocol?.FRCPredicate
        let sort = [NSSortDescriptor(key: "licenseStart", ascending: true), NSSortDescriptor(key: "name", ascending: false), NSSortDescriptor(key: "courseId", ascending: false)]
        req.entity = entity
        req.sortDescriptors = sort
        req.predicate = predicate
        /* NSFetchedResultsController initialization
        a 'nil' 'sectionNameKeyPath' generates a single section */
        var aFetchedResultsController = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: req, managedObjectContext: managedObjectContext!, sectionNameKeyPath:"dateStatus", cacheName: nil)
```

Due to the way that I'm creating the sections based on licenseStart the results of this fetch will be exactly the same as before:

```
[ "licenseStart":1,"id":3, "name":"A",...
  "licenseStart":2,"id":4, "name":"B",...
  "licenseStart":3,"id":6, "name":"B",...
  "licenseStart":4,"id":2, "name":"C",...
  "licenseStart":5,"id":1, "name":"D",...
  "licenseStart":6,"id":7, "name":"E",
]
```

What I'll have in the UITableView will be:

```
[Actually] 
  [A]
  [B]
  [B]
  [C]
[Coming Soon]
  [D]
  [E]
```

Why? because licenseStart are all different and it uses this first element in the NSSortDescriptors to retrieve the data.. this is not the behaviour that I want, what I want is to have the sections exactly in the same order as before but the elements inside arranged different

i.e:

```
[Actually] 
  [C]
  [B]
  [B]
  [A]
[Coming Soon]
  [E]
  [D]
```

**POSSIBLE SOLUTION**

What I thought is to create a new column during the fetchrequest, if I am able to evaluate this expression `licenseStart.doubleValue / 1000 < NSDate().timeIntervalSince1970 ? 0 : 1` at the moment of retrieving the data I would have this new column with 0's and 1's like this in the result:

```
[ "licenseStart":1,"id":3, "name":"A", "status":0, ...
  "licenseStart":2,"id":4, "name":"B", "status":0, ...
  "licenseStart":3,"id":6, "name":"B", "status":0, ...
  "licenseStart":4,"id":2, "name":"C", "status":0, ...
  "licenseStart":5,"id":1, "name":"D", "status":1, ...
  "licenseStart":6,"id":7, "name":"E", "status":1, ...
]
```

And now I could use this **status** for creating the sections in the NSSortDescriptors `[NSSortDescriptor(key: "status", ascending: true),NSSortDescriptor(key: "licenseStart", ascending: true), NSSortDescriptor(key: "name", ascending: true), NSSortDescriptor(key: "courseId", ascending: true)]` for ascending and `[NSSortDescriptor(key: "status", ascending: true),NSSortDescriptor(key: "licenseStart", ascending: false), NSSortDescriptor(key: "name", ascending: false), NSSortDescriptor(key: "courseId", ascending: false)]` for descending.

This would give me the behaviour that I want.. but I haven't been able to figure out a nice and clean way of doing this. I've tried to do this using NSExpressions but I can't use the **less than** with a CoreData fetch..

Also, a possible solution will be creating this new column in my data model and generating this value when saving data, but this is not a valid approach because this licenseStart value has to be compare with the current timestamp every time the user populates this table.

I am asking if someone has a brief idea or a clever solution for this issue.

In MySQL or SQLite is easy to create a new column based on a certain value or expression but in coredata I am a newbie so I am not seeing a clear way to do this.

Thank you so much.

Comment: That is a looooong question. Can you please put a summary somewhere (probably at the top) that shows the end result you want to achieve, and what you're actually getting. This seems a bit like a stream of consciousness - useful for getting your thoughts down, but hard to see what the actual issue is.

Comment: Added a summary, thank you for the feedback @AshleyMills :)

Answer (score 0):

I had a situation where I wanted to section off some elements to be at the top of the list not based on a core-data attribute.  I did the fetch with the fetchedResultsController and then did a single run through to put the elements into on of two arrays (O(n)) keeping the sorted by their original sort. When elements changed I had to find them in my array to change them, but it was not as hard as I expected.

An easier solution might be to use two fetchedResultsController.

Answer (score 0):

Try to not think of CoreData as a regular relational sql database where you can create columns in your queries.

It seems like what you need is just to add another attribute `status` to your entity. Every time you update `licenseStart`, just set the `status` value.

If you're using codegen then either

```
extension Course {
    func updateLicenseStart(date: Date) {
        licenseStart = date
        status = licenseStart.doubleValue / 1000 < Date().timeIntervalSince1970 ? 0 : 1
    } 
}
```

or rename the underlying attribute…

```
extension Course {
    var licenseStart {
        set {
            _licenseStart = newValue 
            status = licenseStart.doubleValue / 1000 < Date().timeIntervalSince1970 ? 0 : 1
        }
        get { return _licenseStart }
    } 
}
```

If you're maintaining your own model class, you can can't add a property observer to an `@NSManaged` var, but you can remove the `@NSManaged` and override the `set` and `get`…

```
public var licenseStart: Date {
    set {
        willChangeValueForKey("licenseStart")
        setPrimitiveValue(newValue, forKey: "licenseStart")
        status = licenseStart.doubleValue / 1000 < Date().timeIntervalSince1970 ? 0 : 1
        didChangeValueForKey("licenseStart")
    }
    get {
        willAccessValueForKey("licenseStart")
        let date = primitiveValueForKey("licenseStart") as? Date
        didAccessValueForKey("licenseStart")
        return date
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, I thought on that solution the first time. But the thing is that when you retrieve the data from the server and save it in Core Data the status will be based on that moment, but what I need is to have the status based on the current timestamp every time the user populate the tableview and I pass the fetchResultsController.fetchedObjects to the tableview delegate methods.

Comment: Ah, I think I understand. How many rows are we talking about? How accurate does the time need to be? Could you do a batch update on app startup / foreground / before the table is populated and set status on each row?

Comment: Is it not a problem of quantity but the app has all this offline complete functionality that let the user even do a course complete offline (it downloads all the content of the course) and then when the connection is active again it launch an update function. So maybe for days there will be an inconsistent sections (it maybe will say *coming soon* when it is *currently*) :S. I was able to create a NSExpression with a propertiesToFetch and create a new value (but I can't be able to use a complex function like the above `licenseStart.doubleValue / 1000 < NSDate().timeIntervalSince1970 ? 0 : 1`